# A limit with $((n-1)!)^{1/(n-1)}$ and other roots of factorials

Tags: limits, asymptotics, factorial

How to prove that the following limit is positive?
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(((n-1)!)^{1/(n-1)}-2\left(\frac{((n-1)!)^3}{(2n-2)!}\right)^{1/(n-1)}\right) >0,$$  where    $ n\in \mathbb Z, n>1 $

Comment: Have you tried to use Stirling formula?

Comment: Are both $\frac{1}{n-1}$ power?

Comment: Yes I tried it , but it's seem  to be difficult

Comment: @abiessu : I'm not convinced your edit was an improvement.

Comment: @dilveen Try to choose unique title

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I respect that; either way, something about the `\left(,\right)` container breaks badly under mobile view.  I recognize that the `\sqrt` base seemed to interfere with the $2$, and maybe that would only be helped with a `\cdot`.  Otherwise, either expression seems roughly equal to me and I was just hoping that the `\sqrt` version wouldn't break as badly.

Comment: ok.... I never thought of what this would look like on a smart phone or anything like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, if you prove that it converges, the condition : $L > 0$ is equivalent to :

$U_n >0$, starting a certain value of n, and $U_n$ being the term you're studying.

Now $U_n >0 \Longleftrightarrow (n-1)! > 2^{n-1}\cdot\dfrac{{(n-1)!}^3}{(2n-2)!}$ since you have positive term

$$U_n >0 \Longleftrightarrow 1 > 2^{n-1}\cdot\frac{{(n-1)!}^2}{(2n-2)!}$$

$$(2n-2)! = (2(n-1))! = (n-1)!n(n+1)\cdots(2n-2) $$

$$
\begin{align}
V_n & =\ln\left( \frac{(2n-2)!}{2^{n-1}\cdot(n-1)!^2}\right) =
 \ln\left( \frac{n (n+1)\cdots(2n-2)}{2^{n-1}\cdot(n-1)!}\right) \\[8pt]
& = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{(\ln(k+n-1) - \ln(k))} -(n-1)\ln(2) \\[8pt]
& = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{\left(\ln\left(1+\frac{n-1}{k}\right)\right)} -(n-1)\ln(2)
\end{align}
$$

$$0 < k < n \Longrightarrow 1 + \frac{n-1}{k} > 2 \Longrightarrow \ln\left(1 + \frac{n-1}{k}\right) > \ln(2)$$ with equality when $k=n-1$.

Sum this from $k=1$ to $(n-2)$ and we get: $$V_n >0 \Longrightarrow (2n-2)! > 2^{n-1}\cdot(n-1)! \Longrightarrow U_n >0$$

This is true for $n>2$, so your limit $L$ is $>0$.

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). You can [edit] your post to improve the formatting: for example, $\ln(2)$ vs $ln(2)$.

Comment: Thx, I don't how to use the double dollars yet, I'll work on that. Is my formating too tough to right though?

Comment: I hope I've left the MathJax formatting less atrocious than I found it.

Comment: No it's perfect, although my answer wasn't complete and was accepted all the same..